# Excel aggregation formula with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logical-operators, excel-2016, array-formulas

I am attempting to determine the minimum nonzero value from a subset of my data, where the subset is indicated/determined by a cell value (as shown).

The formulas shown in bold use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (array formulas) as suggested by other answers to similar questions here and elsewhere.

The data table is shown in blue (rows 1:6 including headers).
The formulae including expected and actual results are shown below it.

[image: Excel screenshot]

The values in the data table were, for the purposes of this example, entered in manually and are exact integers.  Replacing ">0" with ">2" in the formulae give the same results (this is not a rounding issue).

How do I get the expected result in C11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array formulas do not like `AND`

```
=MIN(IF((A2:A6=1)*(B2:B6>0),B2:B6))
```

Use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter

Or if you have 2007 later then:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,B2:B6/((A2:A6=1)*(B2:B6>0)),1)
```

Entered normally.

Or if you have Office 365:

```
=MINIFS(B:B,A:A,1,B:B,">0")
```

Entered normally.

[image]

Comment: The first one has the advantage that it can be used with functions other than MIN (e.g. MEDIAN).

Comment: @WBT yup, there are advantages and disadvantages to all three.  But if you have access to Office 365 it is the best for the MIN issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested if statement instead of the 'AND'

```
{=MIN(IF(F5:F9=1,IF(G5:G9>0,G5:G9)))}
```